# Issues with Spring Integration and process taking time and pausing

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I am looking at some issue that we have in our application. Spring integration is being used to poll a particular directory and then process the files in this directory. It can process 5k 1kb files and sometimes there is a huge pause where the application is doing nothing just sitting idle and then completes the process in 4 minutes. Then the next run will take a bit longer and the one after that takes slightly longer and so on until i restart the application where it goes back to the 4 minutes mark. Has anyone experienced this issue before.

I wrote a standalone version without Spring Integration and dont get the same issue.
I have also below pasted the xml config, just incase i have done something wrong that I can't spot.

Thanks in advance.

```
 <!-- Poll the input file directory for new files.  If found, send a Java File object on inputFileChannel -->
    <file:inbound-channel-adapter directory="file:${filepath}"
        channel="inputFileChannel" filename-regex=".+-OK.xml">
        <si:poller fixed-rate="5000" max-messages-per-poll="1" />
    </file:inbound-channel-adapter>

    <si:channel id="inputFileChannel" />

    <!-- Call processFile() and start parsing the XML inside the File -->
    <si:service-activator input-channel="inputFileChannel"
                          method="splitFile" ref="splitFileService">
    </si:service-activator>

    <!-- Poll the input file directory for new files.  If found, send a Java File object on inputFileChannel -->
    <file:inbound-channel-adapter directory="file:${direcotrypath}" channel="inputFileRecordChannel" filename-regex=".+-OK.xml">

 <si:poller fixed-rate="5000" max-messages-per-poll="250" task-executor="executor" />
    </file:inbound-channel-adapter>

    <task:executor id="executor" pool-size="8"
                   queue-capacity="0"
                   rejection-policy="DISCARD"/>

    <si:channel id="inputFileRecordChannel" />

    <!-- Call processFile() and start parsing the XML inside the File -->
    <si:service-activator input-channel="inputFileRecordChannel"
                          method="processFile" ref="processedFileService">
    </si:service-activator>

    <si:channel id="wsRequestsChannel"/>

    <!-- Sends messages from wsRequestsChannel to the httpSender, and returns the responses on
         wsResponsesChannel.  This is used once for each record found in the input file. -->
    <int-ws:outbound-gateway uri="#{'http://localhost:'+interfaceService.getWebServiceInternalInterface().getIpPort()+'/ws'}"
        message-sender="httpSender"
        request-channel="wsRequestsChannel" reply-channel="wsResponsesChannel" mapped-request-headers="soap-header"/>

    <!-- Handles the responses from the web service (wsResponsesChannel).  Again
         this is used once for each response from the web service -->
    <si:service-activator input-channel="wsResponsesChannel"
        method="handleResponse" ref="responseProcessedFileService">
    </si:service-activator>
```

Comment: Can you get a thread dump when it's at the point where it's "doing nothing"? Use jstack or visualvm. Also, with such a large number of files, you should probably use something other than the default `AcceptOnceFileListFilter` (or reduce its capacity) because you'll eventually OOM.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I have done a thread dump and it looks like the threads are locked waiting for 1 particular thread. Also looking at threads and monitoring the heap doesn't seem to show signs of memory issues. There is a line within the spring documentation that states that, _"The Poller and the TaskExecutor, and they both have to be in tune with each other otherwise you might end up creating an artificial memory leak."_, wondering if it is something like that.

Comment: Can you post the thread dump someplace (e.g. https://gist.github.com/) ?

Comment: Hi Gary,Thanks for your help. I have created 2 gists on the following url, https://gist.github.com/robiulh/c02154c2c280d3900a66
https://gist.github.com/robiulh/5213dc7300b1ed9cb1e8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I surmised in the comment to your question, the (default) `AcceptOnceFileListFilter` does not scale well for a large number of files because it performs a linear search over the previously processed files.

We can make some improvements there; I opened a [JIRA Issue for that](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-3572).

However, if you don't need the semantics of that filter (i.e. your flow removes the input file on completion), you can replace it with another filter, such as an `AcceptAllFileListFilter`.

If you need accept once semantics you will need a more efficient implementation for such a large number of files. But I would warn that when using such a large number of files, if you don't remove them after processing, things are going to slow down anyway, regardless of the filter.